# Can you use a List Comprehension when not appending the iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I decided to start using List Comprehensions and after a little bit of googling I managed to do this:

```
# old way
loaded_sounds = []
for i in assetList_text:
    if i.startswith("loaded_sound"):
        loaded_sounds.append(i.split(',')[1])

# new way
loaded_sounds = [i.split(',')[1] for i in assetList_text if i.startswith("loaded_sound")]
```

Which works perfectly.
So I thought id continue on to the hard for loops and this is where the list comprehension result isn't matching the for loop result.

So this conversion is a little harder as it not only has 2 'if' statment's but its not actually appending the index either.

```
gsc_files = []
for i in assetList_text:
    if ".gsc" in i:
        d = i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "")
        if d not in gsc_files:
            gsc_files.append(d)
```

So this prints out: 6
But with this:

```
gsc_files = [i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") for i in assetList_text if ".gsc" in i if i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") not in gsc_files]
```

It prints out: 0
So I don't know where its going wrong?

Also whilst on the topic of List Comprehensions id like to know their vastness.
Could the following 2 for loops be converted to list comprehensions?

[1]

```
weapon_files = []
x = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/weapons/sp")
for path, subdirs, files in walk(x):
    for fileName in files:
    content = join(x, fileName)
    if content not in weapon_files:
        weapon_files.append(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/weapons/sp/{fileName}")
```

[2]

```
gsc_files_dir = []
for path in gsc_files:
if f"{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD.lower()}" in path:
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
elif os.path.exists(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}"):
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
else:
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
```

Regards,
Phil

EDIT: in response to "DialFrost's" question:

```
f1 = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetlist/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}.csv")
f2 = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetlist/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}_patch.csv")
f3 = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetinfo/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}.csv")
f4 = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/zone_source/english/assetinfo/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}_patch.csv")

with open(f1, 'r') as assetList, open(f2, 'r') as assetListPatch, open(f3, 'r') as assetInfo, open(f4, 'r') as assetInfoPatch:
    assetList_text = assetList.readlines()
    assetListPatch_text = assetListPatch.readlines()
    assetInfo_text = assetInfo.readlines()
    assetInfoPatch_text = assetInfoPatch.readlines()
```

assetList_text is a large(3k+ lines) file.
So here's some info from assetList_text including the ".gsc" lines:

```
fx,weapon/shellejects/fx_smk_weapon_shell_eject
fx,weapon/shellejects/fx_smk_weapon_shell_emit
fx,weapon/shellejects/shotgun
fx,weapon/shellejects/shotgun_resting
fx,weapon/shellejects/shotgun_view
fx,weapon/shellejects/shotgun_view_blurred01
mptype,nazi_zombie_heroes
character,char_zomb_player_0
character,char_zomb_player_1
character,char_zomb_player_2
character,char_zomb_player_3
rawfile,animtrees/zombie_factory.atr
rawfile,clientscripts/_zombie_mode.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/createfx/dlc3_fx.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/createfx/free_city_fx.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/dlc3_code.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/dlc3_teleporter.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/free_city.csc
rawfile,clientscripts/free_city_amb.csc
rawfile,maps/createart/free_city_art.gsc
rawfile,maps/createfx/dlc3_fx.gsc
rawfile,maps/createfx/free_city_fx.gsc
rawfile,maps/dlc3_code.gsc
rawfile,maps/dlc3_teleporter.gsc
rawfile,maps/free_city.gsc
rawfile,rumble/flamethrower
rawfile,rumble/flamethrower_h.rmb
rawfile,rumble/flamethrower_l.rmb
rawfile,vision/zombie_factory.vision
```

Comment: Can you please state what is in `assetList_text`, so we can try it out ourselves?

Comment: You sure you want to do that change for the middle bit? Might look slick now - but in 12 months time if you come back to tweak it you'll be wondering WTF you did! :-)

Comment: Not in front of a computer but you can do all of these with list comprehensions. Instead of using multiple ifs I would use and/or operations. Also you can create intermediate variables with walrus := operators, and check the return is not null to continue the chain. The key thing to understand is the order of processing and/or is left to right, and the evaluation will stop at the earliest point.

Comment: your second conprehension will fail if there hasn't already been a variable declared with the same name....  A list comprehension cannot refer to itself within the comprehension unless the list was initialized prior to the comprehension

Comment: using `append` in list comprehension doesn't really make sense.  The only time list comprehension should be used over a generator expression is when you plan on using the result created from the comprehension in its final state right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace two if statements to one, and add 'and' operator instead of second 'if'. Because I'm not sure what 2 'if' works fine in list-comprehension.
So, change this:

```
gsc_files = [i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") for i in assetList_text if ".gsc" in i if i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") not in gsc_files]
```

To this:

```
gsc_files = [i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") for i in assetList_text if (".gsc" in i) and (i.split(',')[-1].replace("\n", "") not in gsc_files)]
```

'add' operator should compare correct two statements

And I'm not sure what try convert all for loops or just large parts of code in list-comprehension it is good idea, because this can make your code hard to read

Comment: Can you please add a comparison on what changed?
You can also format it so it's a bit more readable, I usually write my comprehensions in multiple lines, they are easier to read IMHO than a for loop.

Comment: This would fail too if this is the first time declaring gsc_files

Comment: this appears to have worked. tyvm!

Comment: p.s

any idea on how i could turn the bottom 2 examples into list comprehensions? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[1] First for loop you mentioned!

```
weapon_files = []
x = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/weapons/sp")
for path, subdirs, files in walk(x):
    for fileName in files:
    content = join(x, fileName)
    if content not in weapon_files:
        weapon_files.append(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/weapons/sp/{fileName}")
```

**Answer: Hope it would help!**
At first, you are trying to access a list which is not created before the list comprehension starts. For your case, you try to create an empty list at first `weapon_files = []`, again list comprehension creates a new list `weapon_files`, but this time, we assign the list with the data that we need to append using `:=`operator. Refer https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions. Now everytime recursively list gets updated for the condition.

```
weapon_files = []
weapon_files = [weapon_files := f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/weapons/sp/{fileName}" for path, subdirs, files in walk(x)  for fileName in files if join(x, fileName) not in weapon_files]
```

[2] Second 'for loop' mentioned!

```
gsc_files_dir = []
for path in gsc_files:
if f"{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD.lower()}" in path:
    #condition 1 ref variable to append ==> var1
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
elif os.path.exists(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}"):
    #condition 2 ref variable to append ==> var2
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
else:
    #condition 3 ref variable to append ==> var3
    dir = join(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/raw/{path}")
    gsc_files_dir.append(dir)
```

**Answer:** Trying list comprehension for this loop statement doesn't bring better readability but still, we can apply. I've shown the template answer using the above commented ref variable names.(var1, var2, var3).

```
gsc_files_dir = [var1 if f"{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD.lower()}" in path else var2 if os.path.exists(f"{WAW_ROOT_DIR}/mods/{CURRENT_SELECTED_MOD}/{path}") else var3 for path in gsc_files]
```

Comment: tyvm sir much appreciated :) (#Upvoted)